# How does your level affect Quest Rewards?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Elder Scrolls: Oblivion, the player had to concern themselves with what level they chose to start and complete quests due to the quality of the reward being based on their level.  Is this Level:Reward ratio still a part of the Elder Scrolls series in Skyrim?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to. At least, [this source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615803-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/60961572) seems to believe so.

It would make sense, too. Even in the last two Fallout games, the rewards were leveled.

Comment: Only a matter of time before Skyrim gets its own [Quest Reward Leveller](http://tesnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=5701) mod, then…

Answer (score 1):

It is, at least for the Main Quest.

When you fight enemies (specifically the Thalmor in Act 2 of the Main quest), at level 50+ (I'm at 62 when I fought them) they dropped Elven and Glass Armor. Enemies that wore heavy armor were dropping Ebony armor and ebony weapons.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Here is [proof](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Leveled_Items) You can see that the same item at different levels of power have a minimum level to spawn, and different Item IDs.

Answer (score 0):

When you're in high levels, you will find stronger armor when looting. Bandits will just wear normal leather, fur, and iron armor unlike oblivion if you're in a high level. Thalmor soldiers will start to wear glass armor instead of Elven. The best way of getting these strong armors are not just to be in a high level, but you can also level smithing, spend perks, and buy and craft materials for high advanced armor and weapons. other things are leveled besides armor such as rewards and looting.